# How to create an egg shape in CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg, shapes

I want to create this custom white color shape without the cart icon in css. How can i do that ?

[image: strong textenter image description here]

Comment: You must provide code but if you did not start yet, if I will be you, I would create a square div with background : blue. Then in it I will create another div with `clip-path: polygon();
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon();` to create the white form you want and then your green cart icon in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **border radius**

Like this

```
border-radius:70% 30% 30% 70% / 60% 40% 60% 40%;
```

like image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDfOd.png)

**Demo**

```css
.cart-div{
  background:#2c44a3;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  padding:50px;
}
.shape{
  background:#fff;
  width:180px;
  height:180px;
  color:#111;
  border-radius:58% 42% 63% 37% / 35% 31% 69% 65%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-div">
  <div class="shape">
  cart icon
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you make different shapes ? visit [here](https://9elements.github.io/fancy-border-radius/#35.58.31.37--200.200)